# Key prefix for redis mutex locks?

Tags: redis, mutex

I have setup redis and redis mutex for a multi-container setup.

```
'mutex' => [
    'mutex' => 'yii\redis\Mutex',
    'namePrefix' => 'mutex_',
],
```

It works, I can see the mutex keys popup occasionally, however the namePrefix seems to do nothing. I can't use the keyPrefix from the yii\redis\Mutex since this is some sort of derived class...?

Reading the documentation for namePrefix (https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-mutex-mutextrait.html#public-properties) this is exactly how I interpret it, however it doesn't seem to stick.

I'm sending sessions to redis as well, with

```
'session' => [
    'class' => yii\redis\Session::class,
    'as session' => craft\behaviors\SessionBehavior::class,
    'keyPrefix' => 'session_',
],
```

And that prefixes the sessions correctly as expected, same with caches.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the namePrefix is only included *before* it is MD5 hashed, meaning that the redis cache key will not include it.

You can apparently configure it with the redis keyPrefix like this

```
'mutex' => [
    'mutex' => [
        'class' => 'yii\redis\Mutex',
        'keyPrefix' => 'mutex_',
    ],
],
```

See https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/12181